# Add Services to Asp.Net Controller Scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

Short: How/is it possible to add services to the scope of all (Odata)Controllers of a assembly without adding them to every controller in the application (i.e. give the assembly a permanent scope with its own services)?

**Context:**

I am currently working on an Odata DDD/Actor based Asp.Net Webservice with the following architecture:

*Wording:*

- Native Domain - The domain which owns the given entity
- Foreign Domain - The domain which want to access the given entity (read only)

Each domain has it's own DbContext to prevent write access to foreign tables but to be still able to read them and to reduce coupling. The DbContext is still scoped.

if you want to access data of foreign domains, you add a read-only model to your db-context and provide a read-only repository, implemented by that foreign domain and provided in the foreign domain (to make sure both repositories use the same dbContext)

this means that you have to provide the same service multiple times with different ctor-parameters and instances (one for each foreign domain which accesses the repository)

I came up with two major solutions:

- each services provides the implementation and interface in its native domain and the interface is extended in the foreign domain. The interface new interface is internal (I would like to avoid this)
- the foreign domain has its own, permanent injection scope which allows it to just provide the native interface without any additional code. this leads to the problem stated above

the latter solution has multiple invariants like creating the extended scope at the start of each command, but I think the stated variant would be the most clean solution.

Comment: Let's suppose every domain has read-only access to all other domains. Does it mean that if you have `n` domains then you will have to create the same read-only model `n-1` times under different namespaces?

Comment: the model and repository class are defined in the native assembly
the repository would require one instance per foreign repository (n-1) instances. 
I hope this answers your question, since I am not too sure what you ment by "define the same model".
each domain is split into 4 assemblies
- Data Access (RW Repositories)
- Api (Shared Code between Domains)
- Presentation (Controller)
- Domain (Business logic and Actors)
RO Repos and RO Model classes are located in the API assembly and instantiated in the foreign repository

Comment: Is there any inheritance hierachy or any shared interface between RW repos/models and RO repos/models? E.g. `IRepository<TDbContext, TEntity>`

Comment: there might be in the future but since I am still working on the architecture and infrastructure this detail has not been resolved yet.
As of yet I would not implement a shared interface, as they use a different model (-class)
As of now it is not intended for the models to be used via interface and combining the  classes of these models feels like too strong of a coupling.
Internal models won't be possible as the foreign dbContext has to contain a DbSet with an explicit data type.